# How to receive SMS?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Am trying to receive incoming SMS on android application but i can't get the coming SMS received, bellow is the code am using.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

> in the mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mdb.com.mmbox">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MySMS" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to look for some examples online but none of them seems to work for me, Please point me where am getting things wrong.

I will appreciate your contribution, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare your permissions out side of your application tag like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mdb.com.mmbox">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MySMS" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: All my applications have permissions bellow